# SQL - Multiplying two columns and producing a third one doesn't work

Tags: sql, multiplication

```
SELECT 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.PURCHASENO, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.NAMN, 
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.ARTNUM, 
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.PURCHASEROW, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.KONTO, 
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.ANTAL, 
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.ENHET, 
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.PRISENHET, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.LEVERANT, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.ADDRESS, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.LEVERANTADDRESS, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.LEVERANTADDRESS2, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.LEVERANTPOSTNR, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.LEVERANTPOSTORT, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.POSTORT, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.ADDRESS2, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.POSTNR, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.KONT1, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.ADDRESS3, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.POSTNR2, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.POSTORT2, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.OWN_NUMBER1, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.DATUM, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.LEVDATUM, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.MOT, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.BETALVILLKOR, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.OVRIGT, 
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.LEVARTNUM, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.BEST, 
  RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME_BEST.ANV_NAMN, 
  RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME_MOT.ANV_NAMN, 
  ANV.NAMN, 
  PURCHASE_HEAD.SIGN,
```

Theese are the two columns that i'm trying to multiply with each other.

```
  PURCHASE_ITEMS.ANTAL * PURCHASE_ITEMS.ENHETSPRIS AS TOTALSUM,
```

And store as TOTALSUM i have no idea what's causing it to not work, i tried it in microsoft query and got the results in a blank blank column but it doesnt actually create a column

```
   PURCHASE_ITEMS.BENAMNING 
 FROM 
   {oj (
    (
      (
        PURCHASE_HEAD PURCHASE_HEAD 



        LEFT OUTER JOIN PURCHASE_ITEMS PURCHASE_ITEMS ON                                         
       PURCHASE_HEAD.PURCHASENO = PURCHASE_ITEMS.PURCHASENO
      ) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME_MOT     
 ON PURCHASE_HEAD.MOT = RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME_MOT.KEY1
    ) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME_BEST 
ON PURCHASE_HEAD.BEST = RP_VIEW_ANV_LOGIN_NAME_BEST.KEY1
   ) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ANV ANV ON PURCHASE_HEAD.SIGN = ANV.LOGIN } 
     WHERE 
      PURCHASE_HEAD.PURCHASENO = 210035 
      ORDER BY 
       PURCHASE_HEAD.PURCHASENO, 
       PURCHASE_ITEMS.PURCHASEROW
```

Comment: Too much to read. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: What do you mean with "blank", `NULL`? Is one of the columns `NULL`? `SELECT 1*NULL` returns `NULL`.

Comment: It wont let me multiply those two columns and storing it as a third one

Comment: "It wont let me"? What do you mean by that? And what do you mean by "storing"? You are selecting, a select never stores anything.

Comment: Also, i don't recognize the from clause as valid sql, what's your dbms?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(isNull(PURCHASE_ITEMS.ANTAL,0) * isNull(PURCHASE_ITEMS.ENHETSPRIS,0)) AS TOTALSUM
```